# Why Firebase is so slow on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, mobile, firebase

I've set up a simple app which pushes and fetches some data to and from Firebase.

The relevant part of the code is:

```
var db = firebase.database();
var notesRef = db.ref("notes");
notesRef.on("child_added", function (item) {
    renderItem(item);
});
```

While on desktop it loads relatively fast (2 seconds), on my iPhone (Safari on iOS 10), I have to wait about 15 seconds. My friends using Android have to wait even more.

What is that happening at all? Why Firebase is so slow on the mobile devices?

Is there a setting I have to enable or something like that?

Comment: Mobile is often a bit slower, but yours sounds different from my experience. It could have to do with the data you download or the connection you download it over or... well... many other factors in between. Can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the behavior and give your numbers for that, so that I can compare?

Comment: Are you on a free account?  I wonder if it is throttled.  Before the change into what Firebase is now, my experiments seemed much faster than that playing with a chat example.  Did you check to make sure that you are actually waiting for the data and not for the data to display on the screen?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It's really just a relativelly small object. It happens even for a number. I don't think it's because of the data. I'll create a demo later.

Comment: @Martin Yes, it's a free account. Rendering is fast (creating a div on the screen–at least my iPhone should be fast enough at that). The slowness comes from Firebase. After it's loaded, adding new items is very fast and editing is also fast.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've set up a [**JSBin**](http://output.jsbin.com/hihokafuka). What is fetching is really, just a number. It takes about 10-15 seconds to load it on my iPhone, via Wifi, in Romania––where [we have fast internet](http://berniespeedtest.com/).

Comment: It load pretty quick for me on my laptop. But somehow I can't get it to run at all on an iPad, neither in Safari nor Chrome. It keeps giving "SyntaxError: unexpected token '>' (line 17)" :-/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It's working on my Macbook. Maybe, try to save the HTML code—that's the whole thing—in a local file.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I pushed it on GitHub pages too: https://ionicabizau.github.io/firebase-test/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Any ideas? Is it working for you on GH Pages?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen There was an arrow function. Can you check again? I can reproduce the slowness even in the XCode emulator.

Comment: I just loaded your Github test page on Chrome on my Android phone, where it loaded in about 2 seconds. In an iOS simulator it indeed take longer, in my case about 5-6 seconds. It could be that the initial redirects simply take that much longer on iOS. Looking at the debug logs might give more insight for that.